# Emulating MVC Architecture with JSON Query

Tags: iphone, ios, json

I'm having trouble emulating MVC architecture when making a JSON query.

Below I'm fetching the data asynchronously by creating a separate NSObject class for handling the query.

That said I'm stumped as to what I should be putting in my query method below in TableViewController.

TableViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //refactoring with MVC
    self.aQueue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.storeLogos = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    [self queryStoreData];

}
   -(void)queryStoreData
{
    aStoreQuery = [StoreQuery queryForStores:self];
}


-(void)query:(StoreQuery *)query queryResult:(id)object
        {
            [self.aQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{

                //JSONKit? 




            }

        }
```

StoreQuery.m

```
@synthesize myConnection, myRequest, storeData;

+(StoreQuery*)queryForStores:(id<StoreQueryDelegate>)aDelegate
{
    StoreQuery *storeQuery = [[[StoreQuery alloc] init] autorelease];
    storeQuery.delegate = aDelegate;
    storeQuery.myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:@"URL"];
    storeQuery.myConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:storeQuery.myRequest delegate:storeQuery];
    storeQuery.storeData = [[NSMutableArray data] retain];
    return storeQuery;

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [self.storeData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.storeData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Connection Error: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
    if (self.delegate) {
        [self.delegate request:self didFailWithError:error];
    }

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    if (self.delegate) {
        [_delegate request:self didFinishWithObject:self.storeData];
    }
}


- (void)dealloc
{
    [myRequest release];
    [myConnection release];
    [storeData release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be inclined to eliminate the whole `StoryQuery` class (you don't appear to really need any of the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` methods here) and just use a block-based network call, using either standard `NSURLConnection` or the wonderful `AFNetworking` framework.

The standard `NSURLConnection` technique:

```
-(void)queryStoreData
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"yoururl"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:self.aQueue
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

                               if (error)
                               {
                                   NSLog(@"%s: error retrieving data = %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
                                   return;
                               }

                               // now parse the results, e.g., if it was JSON:

                               NSError *parseError = nil;
                               self.results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                              options:0
                                                                                error:&parseError];
                               if (parseError)
                               {
                                   NSLog(@"%s: error parsing data = %@", __FUNCTION__, parseError);
                                   return;
                               }

                               // note, all user interface updates must happen on main queue, e.g.

                               [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                                   [self.tableView reloadData];
                               }];
                           }];
}
```

Or using `AFNetworking`:

```
-(void)queryStoreData
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"yoururl"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^
                                         (NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        self.results = JSON;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"JSON network request failed: %@", error);
    }];
    [operation start];
}
```

Comment: By the way, while I've tried to provide real examples of how you might do this, your question makes reference to using the "MVC architecture". The connection between making a network request and proper model-view-controller architecture is thin. But if you were really concerned about proper MVC architecture, you probably wouldn't make the array of results a member of the controller object, but you might actually employ some model object. But I'm assuming the real question was how to perform network operation and consume the results, not MVC architecture.

Answer (score 0):

The Best Example for MVC architectural is [AFNetworking Example](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/master/Example).
It is Been Implemented by using [Blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html).

Comment: AN answer should be more than just a link you should give a description of what the link covers so the answer will stand without the link